# Smart table drag and drop WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, multi-touch

I am trying to add a drag and drop behaviour for a textblock in a smart table application.
I used a window in order to mimic the textblock i wanted to drag. The problem is that on the emulator on my PC the drag works, but on the table it doesn't. From what i could figure out this is due to the fact that on the table the object (the window that mimics the drag object) loses focus.

The application is made in WPF with C#.

Any ideea on how i might fix this?

Comment: Do you mean Microsoft Surface by table?

Answer (score 1):

I've developed a few SMART Table applications using their SDK.  I wouldn't recommend using a window to mimic the textblock.  I usually create a DraggableBorder object and a TextBlock object and then assign the content of the DG object to be the TB object.  This way you can use the usual touch events for the DB object and those objects will be touchable/draggable on the table as well as in the PC emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-touch drag and drop can be pretty tricky.  Grab the Surface Toolkit for Windows Touch and use the drag and drop framework it comes with: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.surface.presentation.surfacedragdrop_members.aspx